# how can I set limit to checkbox selection using radio button values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  a set of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="attending_days" value="06-18-13"/>Tuesday June 18, 2013
<input type="radio" name="attending_days" value="06-18-13"/>Wednesday June 19, 2013
<input type="radio" name="attending_days" value="both_days"/>Both days
```

Checkboxes:

```
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value ="1"/>One<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value ="2"/>Two <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value ="3"/>Three
```

and so, 20 such checkboxes.

Based on what radio button value is selected, I want to limit my checkboxes.

for example for options one or two only 4(out of 20) checkboxes can be selected and for both days(radio 3) eight checkboxes can be selected.

I am not sure how to approach this.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use something like `$('input[name=attending_days]:checked', '#myForm').val()
` to get the value checked radio button, and then based on the result use `if else statements` to block the undesirable checkboxes

Comment: I think you should also mention what happens when (1) the user first clicks 'both_days', then (2) selects more than 4 checkboxes, then (3) user clicks one of the first two radio buttons. What should happen then?

Comment: okay, if user clicks both days, he can select a maximum of any 8 topics from checkboxes and rest would be disabled, unless he changes his mind, unchecks and re-selects something else. 
When it is sny of the first two dates, user can select a maximum of 4 topics and rest get disabled.

Comment: I understand that part. You probably misunderstood my question. I'm pointing out a potential loophole in your design. **IF** the user initially chosen both_days **AND** initially checked more than 4 topics, **THEN AFTER THAT** the user decides to switch back to the one of the first two radio buttons, now you still have **more than 4** checkboxes checked. How should this edge case be handled?

Comment: Or did you mean to say we would have to disabled the first two radio buttons as well, **in case the user checked more than 4 checkboxes**?

Comment: @Terry young: In case user switches radio buttons: the checkbox values will be cleared out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/xLCzp/

```
$('input[name=checkboxes]').on('click', function () {
    var lastOneChecked = $('input[name=attending_days]:last:checked').length,
        iLimit = lastOneChecked ? 8 : 4,
        iChecked = $('input[name=checkboxes]:checked').length;

    if (iChecked > iLimit) {
       return false;
    }

    return true; // added so that anonymous function always returns something
});

$('input[name=attending_days]').on('click', function () {
    $('input[name=checkboxes]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: You just made me smile after a really tough Monday! This is just perfect. :)

Comment: Hi, This is working for me, except: Now Komodo is showing me this warning: anonymous function does not always return a value
and the first checkbox unchecks and checks itself when I click on other checkboxes. Just the first checkbox. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: I've added the 'fix'. The warning you see is because the `return false` is inside the `if` statement. If the logic doesn't go in there, then it is not returning anything. Komodo is simply warning you about this inconsistency. Technically it shouldn't affect the big picture.

Comment: Understood that, but would you happen to know why the first checkbox checks and unchecks itself when I click anything else?

Comment: I might have a hunch. I've changed the selector from `input[type=checkbox]` to `input[name=checkboxes]`. My bad. The original selector literally means **all** checkboxes you have on the page, which is too broad. (Haven't thought of this when I saw other answers were using the same type=checkbox selector)

Comment: In case that's not the cause, if the issue you're having cannot be produced in the demo link I gave, then we need more clues to know if the issue actually relates to this topic.

Comment: I already tried it and that didn't fix anything. It is happenin only in firefox though.

Comment: Does it happen in my demo as well? I'm using Firefox 20, Chrome 26 and IE 9, all without issues. And do you see any JavaScript errors in your browser?

Comment: No, not in your demo, but in my page on firefox alone. No js errors either.

Comment: At least this confirms that in an isolated case, such as the demo, it works. Either you have something more in your actual page that might potentially interfere (e.g. duplicate names elsewhere?), or it could be a completely different issue. Hard to tell from this perspective.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I am trying everything. it is a simple form with just one group of checkboxes. Hopefully, there must be something about it somewhere.

Comment: The nature of only failing in Firefox seems a bit odd. From my current perspective all I can suggest for now is to go through a process of elimination, add an `alert()` or `console.info()` here and there and see what happens, etc. Debugging, what we web developers all love and hate.

Comment: yea, that's exactly what I am gonna do now. Thanks for the pointers, once again.

Answer (score 0):

An example would be using `classes`. You give each `radio button` and its `checkboxes` a class.

```
<input type="radio" class='both' name="attending_days" value="both_days"/>Both days
```

And checkboxes: (note that the checkboxes are **disabled**)

```
<input type="checkbox" class='both' name="checkboxes" value ="1" disabled/>One
<input type="checkbox" class='both' name="checkboxes" value ="2" disabled/>Two
```

Then the JS

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     var class = $(this).attr('class');
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', true); 
     $('.'+class).prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Comment: @Spooky: Thanks for your response. Let me make it more clear. The options are not associated with a particular radio button user can opt for any four or any 8, depending on what days they want to attend and if I do display:none, wouldn't that hide all the checkboxes? I don't want to do that. user can select, disselect but only to a limit which would change as per radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global look-up table of the Ids or values.

```
var lookup = {}; 

lookup['rdo1'] = ['rdo2','rdo3','rdo4']; 
lookup['rdo2'] = ['rdo5','rdo6','rdo7'];
...and so on...
```

Then, when a radiobutton is clicked, in the handler

```
// grabs all of the ids from the lookup
var ids = lookup[$(this).attr('id').toString()]

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    $('#' + ids[i].toString()).addClass('enabledCss');
}
// then loop through the rest of the table and set all of their classes to 'disabledCss' or whatever.
```

Another route you could take is storing the dependent Id's in a `data-*` attribute and grabbing them from there.

```
<input type="radio" data-dependents="2,3,4,5".../>
```

You can then pull them with  `var idStr= $(this).attr('data-dependents');` 
Replace all spaces and split them into an array and then use that array to enable/disable appropriately. var `myArr = idStr.split(idStr.replace(' ',''),',');`

This code will have to be extended out to all of your possibilities, but this is the gist. The `data-*` is probably the most succinct way.

*Note* This is rough, untested code. I just wanted to get you pointed in the right direction. You'll have to fully flesh it out as the rest is basically repeating what I've already shown a bunch more times.